# jsPDF adding base64 string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jspdf

I am trying to convert a blob (`type: 'application/pdf'`) to a base64 string and generate from this string a pdf ([with jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF)) to add a name. My code looks like this:

```
writeToBlob(blob: Blob) {
    var base64;
    var name = "Peter Pan";
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      base64 = reader.result;
      var doc = new jsPDF;
      doc.addImage(base64, 0, 0, 210, 296);
      doc.text(100, 31, name);
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    }
  }
```

My problem is that I'm getting the error `"addImage does not support files of type 'UNKNOWN', please ensure that a plugin for 'UNKNOWN' support is added."`
The first chars of the base64 look like this: `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiW...`

Comment: You are trying to add a pdf as image, that wont work... https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/131

Comment: Thanks, @Endless for replying. Do you have any ideas on how I could make it work?